# Parsing xml file using xmlDocument But failing in parsing because of exception . Please help me in this regard

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to parse an xml file But facing error as output.dat file could not be found.
Firstly I read all xml code in a string and then load it into xmlDocument object but face exception that output.dat not found
here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;
namespace XML
{
    class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        try
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("output.xml");
            String xml = "";
            String line = sr.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                xml += line;
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close();
            XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
            xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Kindly tell me where is error

Comment: When I debug my code xml variable contains all xml from output.xml but got execption at load method

Comment: Why not just use the `Load` method to read to file directly? What is the exact exception message? Typically it will indicate what is wrong with the file.

Comment: LoadXml is for loading from a file. You want what Pooli said below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider replacing

```
   XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
   xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
```

With

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xml)
```